# Kendo-Knockout: Cannot call a function within template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I want to call the `onHover` function but with no suceess. The only way I managed to do this is if the function is global, but this is no what I need.

What I am trying to do is onMouseOver of some element of the dropdown to take its value and do something with it in my viewmodel.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="with: myInnerViewModel">
        <input type="text" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: {data: myData, value:           myValue,template:'<span onMouseOver = \'onHover(this)\' title=\'${data}\'>${data}</span>'}"     />
   <div>     
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myViewModel = function () {

    this.myInnerViewModel = {

        myData : [1, 2 , 3],
        myValue : ko.observable(1),
        onHover : function(e){
            alert(1);    
        }
    };
};


ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/QZWPR/30/

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with location of your function. If you were to change

```
onMouseOver = \'onHover(this)\'
```

to

```
onMouseOver = \'myViewModel.myInnerViewModel.onHover(this)\'
```

then i expect you would see your alert.

OR

you need to use the event binding on your span

```
<span data-bind="event: { mouseover: onHover}">
```

Comment: No, this does not work. Please see the fiddler, I have attached. I tried using $parent, but it also does not work.